# Get / Set stage status jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to add a new status on an stage in the pipeline jenkins.

I don't know if it is possible.

I made many searches, I noticed that quite a lot of people had this interrogation but I did not find real solution.

Do you know one?

Comment: What do you mean by `status`?

Comment: SUCCESS / FAILED / ABORTED ...

Comment: By new status, you want to introduce a new value ,say 'TEST_FAILURE', along with the existing values -- 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED', 'ABORTED', 'UNSTABLE'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: How we can set new status ?

Comment: Even though all steps run correctly, you can use `currentBuild.result='FAILURE'` and force jenkins job to failure at any stage.
Similarly you can do for other 'status'

Comment: Yes but I would like to recover the status of each "Stage" and not that of the complete job

Answer (score -3):

Set it manually from the stage code: currentStage.result =  'FAILURE'

Comment: What version of Jenkins did you use this with?

Comment: There is no currentStage variable, at least until now.